# Mysql multi tables chaining join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, join

There are three tables
table:Continents

```
Continent     Id
Asia           1
Europ          2
North America  3
```

table:Nations

```
Nation        Id
China          1
Korea          2
France         3
UK             4
US             5
Canada         6
```

table:Continents_Nations

```
Continent_id    Nation_id
1                1
1                2
2                3
2                4
3                5
3                6
```

How can I make the following result out?

```
Continent   Nation
Asia        China
Asia        Korea
Europe      France
Europe      UK
North America  US
North America  Canada
```

I have tried the SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `C`
JOIN `C_N` ON `id`=`C_N`.`C_id` 
JOIN `N` ON `C_N`.`N_id`=`N`.`id`
```

But this doens't show what I expect.

And I also want to join more table like "Cities" with "Nations"

**I have tried the example above and it worked out...
This example is brief version of my case and I checked again and found my data is incorrect so it didn't work out.
But the SQL clause has no problem
Thanks for answering**

Comment: What results do you get from that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Continents.Continent,
    Nations.Nation
FROM
    Continents_Nations
INNER JOIN
    Continents
ON
    Continents.Id=Continents_Nations.Continent_id
INNER JOIN
    Nations
ON
    Nations.Id=Continents_Nations.Nation_id
```

To join more table like "Cities" with "Nations" use the same approach: connect them by primary key -> foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.Continent, N.Nation
FROM Continents_Nations AS CN
JOIN Nations    AS N ON(N.Id = CN.Nation_id )
JOIN Continents AS C ON(C.Id = CN.Continent_id )
ORDER BY C.Continent ASC, N.Nation ASC
```